# Business Object WEBI report splitting into multiple pages (not tabs)

Tags: business-objects, webi

I'm trying to create a WEBI report. The specs are a little tricky to figure out, hopefully one of ya'll help me get this resolved.

I have data that looks similar to this:

```
Name       Port         Amount
Apple      APL          100
Google     GOOG         500
Apple      APL          50
Netflix    NFLX         500
Netflix    NFLX         100
```

What I am trying to do in my WEBI report is to have a separate PAGE (not tab) for each specific Port.

User would open report and see all the data on Page 1 with APL like so...

```
 Name       Port         Amount
 Apple      APL          100  
 Apple      APL          50

 Total                   150
```

Now user would click [image]

And this would take him to Page 2, showing the same breakout for GOOG, and Page 3 would have a breakout for NFLX.

How am I able to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two possibilities. You could create a **break** on Port and then in the Manage Breaks pop-up box check the "Start on a new page" checkbox.

[image]

You could also set your Port as a **section** and then in the Format Section pop-up box check the "Start on a new page" checkbox.

[image]

I generally use breaks more than sections, but either one should work for you.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Thank you - marking as answer.